# Can an SqlConnection be initially opened?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm trying to figure out a weird bug in my application. It's one of those "non-reproducible-appearing-only-once-a-month-in-production" type of bugs. I've poured over the code, and currently my best guess is that an SqlConnection is somehow being created opened. That is:

```
var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyComputer;User ID=sa;Password=sa");
// conn.State == ConnectionState.Open here
```

Now, I cannot deliberately reproduce this situation in any way, so the question is - is there some freak condition under which the above can be true; or should I continue looking for the bug elsewhere?

Comment: It is possible that this type of connection is being returned from the internal pool of connections under high load? Create a test-bed that opens and uses lots of connections concurrently. A lot of the time, the connection is not "created", it is "borrowed" from an internal pool, much like the `ThreadPool`. Chances are slim, but it might be a bug inside that puts released connections back in the pool without fully closing them off - code review to make sure all connections are closed in your code too.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I'm attempting this with a pool size of 1. I've verified that I can indeed only open a single connection at a time, but disposing and re-opening still produces a "Closed" state.

Comment: What makes you think that this is the case - do you have an error report?

Comment: @Vilx- My follow on point is that you may have code that doesn't close the connection, but is finished with it. Or there is a race condition internally that means a connection is given out by the pool before it closes. Most of these are highly unlikely, but then again so is your bug. Don't limit your tests to a limited pool size, I would try to replicate the production environment. Leave the pool size to default and just run lots of connections on a few threads.

Comment: @Paddy - I don't know if this is the case, but it's my best guess so far. I see in the DB that something has happened which basically should be "impossible" (my log table in the DB has an action logged with the wrong user ID).

Comment: `using(var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyComputer;User ID=sa;Password=sa")){//insert code here}`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I also tried to set my collection to `null` and then GC. The effect is the same - the connection is `Closed`. Also, judging by the logs, the user was alone in the system at that time. The server is a monster, and there was virtually no load at that time. Unless she was clicking REALLY fast, there shouldn't even have been concurrent HTTP requests (it's a website).

Comment: To be honest - I maybe wouldn't chase this alley too hard.  In my experience when you get something 'impossible' happening, it's generally something I've done, as opposed to a fundamental bug in the framework... (although, sometimes it is the case, however it would seem unusual for such a widely used snippet of code to be buggy like this).

Comment: @Vilx- +1 for Paddy's suggestion. Put code in to check for an existing open connection and either throw a better exception or try to get another un-opened connection to carry on with.

Comment: Is your code always `var conn = ...; conn.Open();`, or is there sometimes code in between acquiring the connection and opening it yourself? If the latter, it's far more likely to be an obscure path that results in two `Open()` calls in your own code.

Comment: @Paddy - No, I don't suspect a bug in framework (though it's a possibility). I think that I might have accidentally performed some kind of (illegal?) combination of actions that resulted in the above freak scenario. But I can't figure out what it could have been.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - this is wrapped inside 3 tons of framework code (not written by me, but I maintain it now). I could try and extract the few relevant lines, but then I might miss the ones that are really to blame. I could post it all, but then you could spend the whole afternoon trying to understand what's going on. :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - No, it's wrapped in layers of framework. I do suspect that there's a bug in there, but I've inspected the relevant execution paths, and this is the only scenario that I can come up with that would produce the mysterious results.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the bug elsewhere in the framework (an opened connection was being passed to the method in a special case I had overlooked before), and since I couldn't reproduce the above situation, nor anyone else seems to be able to reproduce it, I'll venture to say:

**No, you can't get an initially-opened connection from the pool.**

Comment: I shoulda put my comment as an answer :)

Comment: @jgauffin - Hey, that all-caps shout was on purpose! XD

Comment: @Paddy - well, ok, do it. I won't get any rep from accepting my own answer anyway, so might as well give it to someone else. :)

Comment: @Vilx-: Shouting gives me a headache. And I only want those after drinking too much.

Comment: Ah no, it wasn't really an answer - yours actually answers your question, so best left.  Thanks tho.